# How to create a tensorflow dataset from a CSV file in R to train a Multilayer perceptron

Tags: r, csv, tensorflow

I have been working several times with tensorflow in Python. I always use keras because it has a very nice syntax.

Currently I have to implement a multilayer perceptron un R.

In the tutorial that appear in:
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorial_mnist_pros.html

They directly load the mnist dataset in their own format:

```
input_dataset <- tf$examples$tutorials$mnist$input_data
mnist <- input_dataset$read_data_sets("MNIST-data", one_hot = TRUE)
```

And they use it using their functions to obtain the batches:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    batches <- mnist$train$next_batch(100L)
    batch_xs <- batches[[1]]
    batch_ys <- batches[[2]]
    sess$run(train_step,feed_dict = dict(x = batch_xs, y_ = batch_ys))
}
```

I have my dataset in a csv file and I load it into a data frame, but I have absolutely no idea about how to transform it in a tensorflow dataset in order to use functions like next_batch.

Any tip to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

See class [`Dataset`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L105) and some helper functions in [base.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py) in TF.

Reference:

- [tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py)
- [tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py)

Comment: Thanks, base.py looks useful, I need to find out if it is possible to use it from R.

Comment: I have found this link https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/using_tensorflow_api.html#simple_example